# porting code from Linux to MinGW

Tags: c++, linux, mingw, portability, preprocessor-directive

I am writing a small class which can create/remove/rename/search for files and directories on the PC.

I successfully wrote the class and run on Linux.

When I was trying to run the same Class Code in MinGW, it was giving an error. 
I could narrow down to: 
mkdir function in Linux, Cygwin has 2 Arguments (directory name , mode permissions)
but in MinGW has only one argument(directory name).

My query is : a) What is the best way to make the code work on both OSs. b) Though I never used, I heard Preprocessor directives can be put like #ifdefined .....#endif ..or some thing of that sort c) Is using Preprocessor directives a good programming practice. As I learnt, preprocessor directives should be used minimally.

Could some one help me in this:

Here is my Code which works on Linux and Cygwin:

```
#include "BioDatabase.h"
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


BioDatabase::BioDatabase() {
   string s = getcwd(NULL,0);
   changeDirectory(s,"*");
}

BioDatabase::BioDatabase(string directoryName, string extension)
{
   changeDirectory(directoryName, extension);
}

bool BioDatabase::createDirectory(string st)
{
     if( mkdir(st.c_str(),0755) == -1)
    {
       cerr <<endl<<"BOSERR-BioDatabase, createDirectory: Path or file function not found or Permission denied\n\n";
       return false;
    }
    flag =1;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could code something like

```
 #if _POSIX_C_SOURCE
     if( mkdir(st.c_str()) == -1)
 #else
     if ((mkdir(st.c_str(),0755) == -1)
 #endif
```

See also [feature_test_macros(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) man page.

Comment: Hi, THIS suggestion worked for me. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

1) you can use pre-processors to do one thing on one platform, and something different on another.  EG:

```
#ifdef mingw32 
/* windows specific code, like mkdir()... */
#else
/* other platform code, like a different way to call mkdir() */
#endif
```

2) Yes, you're absolutely right: limit using them as much as you can.  *but* you'll quickly find out you can't avoid them entirely.

3) The best thing to do is to use a script that checks for
   functionality rather than do it on a per-operating system basis.
   Typically this involves writing a configure script (or
   similar), which is a whole other learning curve.  Still, it lets
   you port to new platforms by checking for functionality rather than
   adding the platform to a long list.

Comment: First of , thank you for the answer. I tried, but it was still giving the same error. How will the compiler know that mingw32 is a different Os ?? On the Command while compiling do I need to give some flags ? Thank you once again.

Comment: Compilers have pre-defined flags a lot of the time for detecting the architecture, such as `__linux__` and `mingw32`.  The trick, of course, is always to know what the actually name you need is.